# ubuntu 14 04 installation problems

Tags: 14.04, system-installation

I have burned the .iso file to a DVD. But when I put the DVD in the DVD-ROM drive and reboot nothing happens. I get no options to install. The only thing that I get is a missing boot manager press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd>. What do I need to do to fix this?

This is a clean install on a blank hard drive and older computer?

Answer (score 2):

- Your system is setup to boot from harddrive rather from CD/DVD
- Your harddisk does contain a non bootable OS (from the message, i guess it was windows)

Options:

- Verify that your system is setup for booting from CD/DVD drive. Go into the BIOS settings and check the boot order
- Verify the DVD (if not applicable to check from within the burning tool, test the disc with another computer it it boots correctly)
- disconnect any USB harddrives or dongles during installation

Comment: I am concerned that the image I have is incomplete. What all folders should I be seeing?

Comment: i cannot list all the items which should be in the root, but if you burn your image it should check it against the MD5 file (be sure to have this one, too) and also should have the option to verify the burned image. If you use Ubuntu, you should have the context menu option 'burn image' or something, which would usually take care of writing the image correctly.

Comment: yeah there is no folder named root

Comment: LOL! Okay, sorry. Seriously, can you list the DVD content here?

Comment: .disk boot casper dists install isolinux pool preseed test autorun.inf md5sum.txt readme.diskdefines and wubi.exe

Comment: i have no 14.04 ISO here to try, but all my other images have a 'live' folder when mounted!? What is the content of .disk/cd_type ?

Comment: there has to have been some kind of error on the iso burning or something im going to re download and burn again.